# Correlation and then a multiple regression

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, spss, pearson-r

I have used a pearson correlation to see if certain variables that other people have found to predict the Dependent variable do occur (so I can use them as covariates later on). I then wanted to do a multiple regression, however pearson correlation shows that not all the variables that other people have found to predict the dependent variable are  significant. Do I include these in the multiple regression or do I leave them out because they were non-significant?

Comment: Welcome to CV. One issue with nonsignificant, bivariate correlations is that, in a multivariate context like multiple regression, significance can be masked due to moderating effects. This is a challenge to your inferences. Due diligence suggests that you check for possible moderator effects in your information.

Comment: What's the reason for doing this exercise?  Unless it's to provide independent evaluation of previous models, it might behoove you to include all variables considered important, regardless of how "significant" or not they seem to be.